# Deploying an assembly to a FTP server using Maven 2

Tags: maven-2, ftp, distribution

I have a project divided into several sub-modules (each of them are `jar` libraries):

```
myapp
    myapp-commons
    myapp-client
    myapp-server
```

I've configured my `pom.xml` in order to create 3 assemblies (`client.zip`, `oracle.tar.gz` and `server.tar.gz`) that are finally stored in the `myapp/target` directory.
I want now is to distribute two of them (`oracle.tar.gz` and `server.tar.gz`) to a server using FTP.

Even if I didn't try yet, I know that I can do that quite easily using some lines of Ant inside my `pom.xml`, but I don't really like this option (I will solve my problem with Ant only if there are no other solution).
There are some SO questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069529/maven-site-deploy-using-ftp) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255414/deploy-maven-site-using-ftp-ant-task)) that offer solutions for that.

My question is to know if there is a better way to do that? I know about the Wagon Maven2 plugin but I didn't succeed in configuring it in order to deploy the assemblies (and **not** the JAR created).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say in your question, the Ant approach is not ideal, but if you don't find an alternative, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405979/using-maven-for-deployment/1406397#1406397) shows how to use the antrun plugin to deploy with FTP. The

Update, based on your updated question this part is less relevant, I'll leave it in to help others though.

The [wagon-ftp plugin](http://maven.apache.org/wagon/wagon-providers/wagon-ftp/) allows you to connect to FTP servers. I've not tried this, but you may then be able to bind the deploy-plugin's [deploy-file goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) to an appropriate phase to deliver the files to the FTP server (some hints on usage at [this blog](http://www.lousycoder.com/blog/index.php?/archives/108-Using-maven-deploydeploy-file-with-wagon-ftp-its-complicated!.html)).

Comment: Sorry, I said "cargo" in my question, but I meant "wagon" in fact ;o)

Answer (score 2):

The way to deploy artifacts using FTP is documented in [Deployment of artifacts with FTP](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-ftp.html):

> In order to deploy artifacts using FTP
>   you must first specify the use of an
>   FTP server in the
>   distributionManagement  element of
>   your POM as well as specifying an
>   extension  in your build  element
>   which will pull in the FTP artifacts
>   required to deploy with FTP:
>
> ```
>   ...
>
>   <!-- Enabling the use of FTP -->
>   <distributionManagement>
>     <repository>
>     <id>ftp-repository</id>
>     <url>ftp://repository.mycompany.com/repository</url>
>     </repository>
>   </distributionManagement>
>
>   <build>
>     <extensions>
>       <extension>
>         <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
>          <artifactId>wagon-ftp</artifactId>
>          <version>1.0-alpha-6</version>
>       </extension>
>     </extensions>
>   </build>
> ```
>
> Your `settings.xml`  would contain a `server` element where the `id` of that element matches `id` of the FTP repository specified in the POM above:
>
> ```
> <settings>
>
>   ...
>
>   <servers>
>     <server>
>       <id>ftp-repository</id>
>       <username>user</username>
>       <password>pass</password>
>     </server>
>
>   </servers>
>
>   ...
>
> </settings>
> ```

Now, my understanding is that you want to use such settings for a subset of the produced assemblies only. To do so, I'd create a dedicated module to produced the assemblies to be distributed using FTP and **override** the `distributionManagement` element with the FTP setup in this module only.